# How to display the form with all the fields of an object in edit mode in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have table which display the records of particular object and table shows only 4-5 fields also each row having edit button. I want to display the all the fields of that record in edit format after clicking on edit button.

Is this possible? Please suggest me any alternate way if this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [force:recordEdit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordEdit) component

> A force:recordEdit component represents the record edit UI for the specified recordId.

OR

[force:editRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:editRecord/documentation) event for your use case.

> This event opens a page to edit the record specified by recordId.

Refer to the documentation on the component and event for implementation details and examples.